# Angular excel export

Tags: angularjs, node.js, excel, export, factory

Here ,I am calling my node program and getting data from MYSQL and on click exporting in excel.

```
$scope.exportToExcel=function(){    
    $http.get("/getDetails").then(function(response){ 
          console.log(response.data)
          $scope.details = response.data[1].data; // here you will get data
     },function(res){
          console.log("Error",res) //error occured
     });


      $scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){ // ex: '#my-table'
            var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport');
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100); // trigger download
        }

var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName){
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    })
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tableToExcel' of undefined
```

Please help with the same.

**EDIT:1**

```
app.controller('myctrl', ['$scope','$http','$timeout','Excel', function($http,$timeout,Excel) {

$scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){
$http.get("/getNodeService").then(function(response){ 
      console.log(response.data)
      $scope.details = response.data[1].data; 

 var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,'WireWorkbenchDataExport',$scope.details);
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},10000);
});
};

}]);

app.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName,details){
console.log(details);
                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName,table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;
            }
        };
    });
```

In Edit Code ,i am able to download excel with header but my mysql data is not coming in that , what i need to change in my code so that i can download with my data.
Please help.

**Solved Edit 2:**

```
$scope.exportToExcel=function(tableId){
$http.get('/getDetails').then(function(response){ 
      console.log(response.data)
      $scope.details = response.data[1].data; // here you will get data

 var exportHref=Excel.tableToExcel(tableId,"worksheetName",$scope.details);
            $timeout(function(){location.href=exportHref;},100);
});
};

}]);
app.factory('Excel',function($window){
        var uri='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
            template='<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
            base64=function(s){return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));},
            format=function(s,c){return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g,function(m,p){return c[p];})};
        return {
            tableToExcel:function(tableId,worksheetName,details){

                var table=$(tableId),
                    ctx={worksheet:worksheetName || 'Worksheet',table:table.html()},
                    href=uri+base64(format(template,ctx));
                return href;

            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    myApp.factory('Excel', function($window) {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function(s) {
            return $window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
        },
        format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        };

    return {
        tableToExcel: function(tableId, worksheetName) {
            var table = $(tableId),
                ctx = {
                    worksheet: worksheetName,
                    table: table.html()
                },
                href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            return href;
        }
    };
}).controller('MyCtrl', function(Excel, $timeout) {
    $scope.exportToExcel = function(tableId) { // ex: '#my-table'
        var exportHref = Excel.tableToExcel(tableId, 'sheet name');
        $timeout(function() {
            location.href = exportHref;
        }, 100); // trigger download
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you use code sample option in the editor to show your code much better.

Comment: i dnt want to mention  this line .controller('MyCtrl', function(Excel, $timeout) because i m using in top and then wring only function..please help i m very much new in this.

Comment: Use exportToExcel() function in your existing controller and make sure that you have inject the Excel, and $timeout in your controller and Excel libraries were injected

Comment: can u please tell me in code.I have injected timeout and mention Excel as function.still same error tableToExcel undefine..

Comment: but i have already mention controller above how to write now?please help.I am writing inside controller only i want to mention functions?

Comment: How to change name for exported excel sheet with current timestamp?Means Excel sheet name should come with time.?