# Generated excel is blank

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting data from the backend and exporting it to excel using angularjs. When I click on the export button, it is downloading a blank excel sheet instead of my data.

I could not trace the issue, I tried using `$timeout` but the excel is still generated blank without data. Any inputs?

**EDIT**

When there is a backend call, it is not waiting until the response is back from backend and generating the blank file, i tried using `$timeout` function but didn't work.

Code:

```
myApp.controller('modalCtrlTest', function ($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.dataToExport = function(){
      $scope.allDataInfomation();

    }
    $scope.allDataInfomation = function(){

/*  $scope.jsonToExport = [
    {
        "col1data": "1",
      "col2data": "Fight Club",
      "col3data": "Brad Pitt"
    },
    {
        "col1data": "2",
      "col2data": "Matrix (Series)",
      "col3data": "Keanu Reeves"
    },
    {
        "col1data": "3", 
      "col2data": "V for Vendetta",
      "col3data": "Hugo Weaving"
    }
  ];*/

  //service call to get the data from backend
  UserService.getDataFromBackEnd().then(
    function(response){
      $scope.jsonToExport = response;
    });
    $scope.fileName = "report";
    $scope.exportData.push(["#", "Movie", "Actor"]);
  // Data 
    angular.forEach($scope.jsonToExport, function(value, key) {
    $scope.exportData.push([value.mID, value.mName, value.mActor]);
    });
  }

    //export button directive code
    $scope.exportData = [];
  var fileName
    $scope.download = function() {  //This method is called when clicked on the Export  button
        $scope.dataToExport();
        function datenum(v, date1904) {
            if(date1904) v+=1462;
            var epoch = Date.parse(v);
            return (epoch - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        };

        function getSheet(exportData, opts) {
            var ws = {};
            var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
            for(var R = 0; R != $scope.exportData.length; ++R) {
                for(var C = 0; C != $scope.exportData[R].length; ++C) {
                    if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                    if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                    if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                    if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
                    var cell = {v: $scope.exportData[R][C] };
                    if(cell.v == null) continue;
                    var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

                    if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                    else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                    else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                        cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                        cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                    }
                    else cell.t = 's';

                    ws[cell_ref] = cell;
                }
            }
            if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
            return ws;
        };
        function Workbook() {
            if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
            this.SheetNames = [];
            this.Sheets = {};
        }
        var wb = new Workbook(), ws = getSheet($scope.exportData);
        /* add worksheet to workbook */
        wb.SheetNames.push('sampleFile');
        wb.Sheets['sampleFile'] = ws;
        var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});

        function s2ab(s) {
            var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
            var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
            for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
            return buf;
        }
        saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), $scope.fileName+'.xlsx');
    };
});
```

html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-ef btn-ef-3 btn-ef-3c mb-10" ng-click="download()">Export <i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
```

Reffered link: [Angular excel export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338173/angular-excel-export)

I tried using `$timeout` to generate the excel in order to get the data from backend but still the excel generated is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try following code changes. you need to push the changes in 
`$scope.exportData` after you received the response from backend

```
myApp.controller('modalCtrlTest', function ($scope, UserService) {
    $scope.exportData = [];

    $scope.allDataInfomation = function(){
        UserService.getDataFromBackEnd().then(
        function(response){
          $scope.jsonToExport = response;
          $scope.fileName = "report";  // need to push data here after response
          $scope.exportData.push(["#", "Movie", "Actor"]);
            angular.forEach($scope.jsonToExport, function(value, key) {
                $scope.exportData.push([value.mID, value.mName, value.mActor]);
            });
            $scope.createExcelData();
        });         
    }

    //export button directive code
    $scope.download = function() {  //This method is called when clicked on the Export  button

        $scope.allDataInfomation();
    }
    $scope.createExcelData = function() {
        function datenum(v, date1904) {
            if(date1904) v+=1462;
            var epoch = Date.parse(v);
            return (epoch - new Date(Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        };

        function getSheet(exportData, opts) {
            var ws = {};
            var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
            for(var R = 0; R != $scope.exportData.length; ++R) {
                for(var C = 0; C != $scope.exportData[R].length; ++C) {
                    if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
                    if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
                    if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
                    if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
                    var cell = {v: $scope.exportData[R][C] };
                    if(cell.v == null) continue;
                    var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

                    if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
                    else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
                    else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                        cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                        cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
                    }
                    else cell.t = 's';

                    ws[cell_ref] = cell;
                }
            }
            if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
            return ws;
        };
        function Workbook() {
            if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
            this.SheetNames = [];
            this.Sheets = {};
        }
        var wb = new Workbook(), ws = getSheet($scope.exportData);
        /* add worksheet to workbook */
        $scope.exportData.length = 0;
        wb.SheetNames.push('sampleFile');
        wb.Sheets['sampleFile'] = ws;
        var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});

        function s2ab(s) {
            var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
            var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
            for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
            return buf;
        }
        saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), $scope.fileName+'.xlsx');
    };
});

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-ef btn-ef-3 btn-ef-3c mb-10" ng-click="download()">Export <i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
```

Comment: I tried as below way, when user click on Export for the first time, the excel is blank ,It is not waiting until the response is back from backend.When clicked on export for second time, the first time clicked response is being exported to the excel.

Comment: Each time when clicked on export, it is showing previous exported data and newly retrieved data from backend. First time it is showing correctly. When requested to export for second time with new information, it is showing first data plus again adding table header followed by new information..

Comment: It is not working, first time it is showing the data from second time it is showing only the table header, data is blank. I think because of this  $scope.exportData.length = 0; no data is exported to the excel

Comment: ok. i changed the posotion of  $scope.exportData.length = 0. can you try one more time.